# How to use/translate NetTopologySuite geomety to GeoJSON for use in Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nettopologysuite

I am using NetTopologySuite 2.0 and I would like to return some geo data thru my Web API. I would like to use GeoJSON for DTOs, but I can not find any GeoJSON model which is compatible with NTS. I know there exist NTS reader/writer for GeoJSON, but its output is string and i would like to have an object, because I would like to see a model also thru swagger. I would like to have Web API method similar to this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public GeometryGeoJsonDto GetData()
{
  //...
  Geometry geometry; //result of processing
  GeometryGeoJsonDto result = geometry.ToDto();
  return result;
}
```

Am I missing something?